# $(document).ready not Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to run jQuery and WebMethods with ASP.NET; I have added a ScriptManager to the **master page**, and a content on the content page

```
<asp:Content ID="ch" ContentPlaceHolderID="cHead" runat="server">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
          alert("hi");
       });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

However this never fires, what am I missing?

Comment: The JavaScript works in jQuery 1.6 as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/VRA98/ Something else is wrong. Does your browser indicate an error icon for JavaScript? When you view your page source, is the JavaScript there? (Maybe code on the server side is hiding a control that contains the JavaScript).

Comment: post your jquery include code..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Verify the following steps.

1. Did you include jquery
2. Check for errors in firebug

Those things should fix the problem

Comment: If this doesn't help and you get no errors, try to put some `console.log('step info')`s through the steps and watch out whether or not are all of them outputted to console at the right time... because: jQuery CAN ***silent*** exit in some error cases...

Answer (score 35):

One possibility when `ready` stops working is that you have javascript code somewhere that is throwing an exception in a `$(document).ready(...)` or `$(...)` call, which is stopping processing of the rest of the `ready` blocks. Identify a single page on which this is occurring and examine it for possible errors in other places.

Comment: I had a similar problem - there were indeed a couple of jQuery-related errors in my page. Once they were fixed, everything worked.

Comment: For me, this occurred because I had forgotten to do a `bower install` to install some third-party JS libraries. When I tried to load one of the files from those libraries, Laravel rendered a 404 page instead, which obviously threw an error due to containing non-JS code.

Comment: I wish I found your answer sooner! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, this was the cause of the problem for me too. I didn't think that errors in other blocks would stop all document.readys

Comment: This was exactly my problem.  A JS function was silently throwing an exception, killing all my remaining javascript.  Fixing that uncaught exception fixed it.  Upvote from me!  ;-)

Comment: Totally worked... An error was throwing earlier in the script

Answer (score 16):

Instead of using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* your code */ });
```

Use this:

```
jQuery(function($) { /* your code */ })(jQuery);
```

It is more concise and does the same thing, it also doesn't depend on the `$` variable to be the jQuery object.

Comment: Check you commenting, that code will not work. The comment should be `/* your code */` and your example would be correct

Comment: @harshal lonare, yes it does work with that code, but why not with $(document)?

Comment: what did yo mean with (jQuery), it annoy my script

Answer (score 3):

Check for your script has to be write or loaded after jQuery link.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

//after link >> write codes...

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      //your code
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if the host page is HTTPS and the included javascript source path is HTTP. The two protocols must be the same, HTTPS. The tell tail sign would be to check under Firebug and notice that the JS is "denied access".

Answer (score 1):

I had copy pasted my inline `js` from some other `.php` project, inside that block of code there was some `php` code outputting some value, now since the variable wasn't defined in my new file, it was producing the typical `php` `undefined warning/error`, and because of that the `js` code was being messed up, and wasn't responding to any event, even `alert("xyz");` would fail silently!! Although the erronous line was way near the end of the file, still the `js` would just die that too,

**without any errors!!! >:(**

Now one thing confusing is that debugger console/output gave no hint/error/warning whatsoever, the `js` was dying silently.

So try checking if you have `php` inline coded with the `js`, and see if it is outputting any error. Once removed/sorted your `js` should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> function pageLoad() {
>     console.log('pageLoad');
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         alert("hi");
>     });
> };
> ```

its the ScriptManager  ajax making the problem
use pageLoad() instead

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, take a look:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" />
```

vs

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

The first method is actually wrong, however the browser does not complain at all.
You need to be sure that you are indeed closing the javascript tag in the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I got it solved this way:

```
// wait until DOM is loaded
$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log("DOM is ready");

    // wait until window is loaded (images, links etc...)
    window.onload = function() {

        console.log("window is loaded");
        var your_html_element = document.getElementById("your_html_element_ID"),

    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all solutions here and web searched for over an hour.

My issue turned out to be needing to clear the cache. I noticed that what I had in localintranet.js was not reflecting what I had typed. I checked this by (In Chrome) opening up dev tools with F12, clicking on the "Sources" menu option and hten drilling down to my scripts folder and the .js actual file name.