# jquery - document ready is not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have a web page with multiple iframes in it.

I've created a custom dropdown looking at [**this**](http://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/index4.html).

I've created the same dropdown in all the iframes. And when I load the page.

Dropdown works fine in all the iframes when opened in Chrome browswer.

But when I open the same in Mozilla. Only in the one page the dropown working fine.

In other iframes when navigated to it. It's not working fine. It's appearing like this.

[image: Image1]

Someone help me out. I did google and found these posts.

[**$(document).ready not working**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085964/document-ready-not-working), [**javascript Document ready firefox (jQuery)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855955/javascript-document-ready-firefox-jquery). But it didn't help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Posting your code would be more helpful than a poorly cropped screenshot.

Comment: There's no error in creating the dropdown or in the console.log. I could post you the code but that's kinda restricted for me right now.

Comment: How can I add a iframe in fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by replace `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` to `$(windown).load(function() { ... })` in the `.js` file which is loaded int he `index.html` file.